# GMAIL API ACCESS ISSUE

Tags: gmail-api

[image]I am having issue while using the GMAIL API, earlier this used to work but suddenly it started showing me issue of Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch. Please do let me know what needs to be done.
I tried creating the credentials again but still facing the same issue.

Comment: This might help https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ

Comment: Did you visit the URL that is displayed to you and check that you have added that redirect URI?

Comment: Yes I tried the same but still it is giving me the same issue. It works on local when i run through the code. But when I host the same on the server it doesn't.

Comment: Below is the error message faced by me.
------------------------------------------------------------------
Access is denied
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied

Source Error:


Line 29:         {
Line 30:             Response.Write(ex.Message);
Line 31:             throw ex;
Line 32:         }
Line 33:     }